# I get error: "TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined. " in javascript testing file

Tags: javascript, arrays, solidity, truffle

```
  it("should not allow non-owner to delete people", async function(){
    let instance = await People.deployed();
    await instance.createPerson("Lisa", 35, 160, {from: accounts[2], value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether")});
    await truffleAssert.fails(instance.deletePerson(accounts[2], {from: accounts[2]}), truffleAssert.ErrorType.REVERT);
  });
  it("should allow the owner to delete people", async function(){
   let instance = await People.new();
   await instance.createPerson("Lisa", 35, 160, {from: accounts[2], value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether")});
   await truffleAssert.passes(instance.deletePerson(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0]}));
  });
```

Using truffle testing suite I get this result:

```
 Contract: People
    √ should't create a person with age over 150 years (134ms)
    √ shouldn't create a person without payment (143ms)
    √ should set seniour status correctly (333ms)
    √ should set age correctly (65ms)
    1) should not allow non-owner to delete people
    > No events were emitted
    2) should allow the owner to delete people
    > No events were emitted


  4 passing (898ms)
  2 failing

  1) Contract: People
       should not allow non-owner to delete people:
     TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\peopletest.js:31:65)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

  2) Contract: People
       should allow the owner to delete people:
     TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\peopletest.js:36:64)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The last two tests should have worked as they did for other students. However, I have the same TypeError.
I don't understand why it can't recognize array syntax.

Comment: It looks like `accounts` is not defined (which makes sense -  I don't see a declaration anywhere in your code...) Perhaps you meant `web3.eth.accounts` or something like that?

Comment: Can you show your complete test file?

Comment: I have fixed the issue, although I don't know exactly how.